# Calling web service and getting null for response object

Tags: c#, wcf, soap

I am working with a 3rd party web service which is written in Java/Axis.  I have not worked much with WCF so I am trying to feel my way through this.  I was able to generate the class from the wsdl and using Fiddler I am able to see the call being made to the service, and a response being returned.  But in my code, my response is empty and I am not sure why I am not seeing the response.  I did read one post about the namespace, and tried to update it, but no luck.  Below is the generated class, the wsdl and the response from the web service.  Is there an issue with the auto generated class?  Why is my response not being consumed by the C# code?

This is the generated class.  I only included the methods I am calling since this file is over 5000 lines and most of it will not be used by us.

```
[GeneratedCodeAttribute("wsdl", "4.0.30319.18020")]
[DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[WebServiceBindingAttribute(Name = "grandeFacadeSoapBinding", Namespace = "http://localhost:8081/axis/services/grandeFacade")]
public partial class grandeFacadeService : SoapHttpClientProtocol
{
    private SendOrPostCallback EnterpriseObjectsOperationCompleted;

    private SendOrPostCallback EnterpriseObjecOperationCompleted;

    public grandeFacadeService()
    {
        this.Url = "http://example.com:8081/axis/services/grandeFacade";
    }       

    public event EnterpriseObjectsCompletedEventHandler EnterpriseObjectsCompleted;

    public event EnterpriseObjecCompletedEventHandler EnterpriseObjecCompleted;

    [SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("", RequestNamespace = "http://localhost:8180/grandeFacade/services/grandeFacade", ResponseNamespace = "http://localhost:8180/grandeFacade/services/grandeFacade", Use = SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    [return: XmlElementAttribute("EnterpriseObjectsReturn")]
    public WebServiceResp EnterpriseObjects([Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("EnterpriseObjValues")] EnterpriseObjValues[] EnterpriseObjValues)
    {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("EnterpriseObjects", new object[] { EnterpriseObjValues });
        return ((WebServiceResp)(results[0]));
    }

    public IAsyncResult BeginEnterpriseObjects(EnterpriseObjValues[] EnterpriseObjValues, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
    {
        return this.BeginInvoke("EnterpriseObjects", new object[] { EnterpriseObjValues}, callback, asyncState);
    }

    public WebServiceResp EndEnterpriseObjects(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        object[] results = this.EndInvoke(asyncResult);
        return ((WebServiceResp)(results[0]));
    }

    public void EnterpriseObjectsAsync(EnterpriseObjValues[] EnterpriseObjValues)
    {
        this.EnterpriseObjectsAsync(EnterpriseObjValues, null);
    }

    public void EnterpriseObjectsAsync(EnterpriseObjValues[] EnterpriseObjValues, object userState)
    {
        if ((this.EnterpriseObjectsOperationCompleted == null))
        {
            this.EnterpriseObjectsOperationCompleted = new SendOrPostCallback(this.OnEnterpriseObjectsOperationCompleted);
        }
        this.InvokeAsync("EnterpriseObjects", new object[] { EnterpriseObjValues}, this.EnterpriseObjectsOperationCompleted, userState);
    }

    private void OnEnterpriseObjectsOperationCompleted(object arg)
    {
        if ((this.EnterpriseObjectsCompleted != null))
        {
            InvokeCompletedEventArgs invokeArgs = ((InvokeCompletedEventArgs)(arg));
            this.EnterpriseObjectsCompleted(this, new EnterpriseObjectsCompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Results, invokeArgs.Error, invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState));
        }
    }

    [SoapDocumentMethodAttribute("", RequestNamespace = "http://localhost:8180/grandeFacade/services/grandeFacade", ResponseNamespace = "http://localhost:8180/grandeFacade/services/grandeFacade", Use = SoapBindingUse.Literal, ParameterStyle = SoapParameterStyle.Wrapped)]
    [return: XmlElementAttribute("EnterpriseObjecReturn")]
    public wsResponse EnterpriseObjec(EnterpriseObjValues EnterpriseObjValues)
    {
        object[] results = this.Invoke("EnterpriseObjec", new object[] { EnterpriseObjValues });
        return ((wsResponse)(results[0]));
    }

    public IAsyncResult BeginEnterpriseObjec(EnterpriseObjValues EnterpriseObjValues, AsyncCallback callback, object asyncState)
    {
        return this.BeginInvoke("EnterpriseObjec", new object[] { EnterpriseObjValues}, callback, asyncState);
    }

    public wsResponse EndEnterpriseObjec(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
    {
        object[] results = this.EndInvoke(asyncResult);
        return ((wsResponse)(results[0]));
    }

    public void EnterpriseObjecAsync(EnterpriseObjValues EnterpriseObjValues)
    {
        this.EnterpriseObjecAsync(EnterpriseObjValues, null);
    }

    public void EnterpriseObjecAsync(EnterpriseObjValues EnterpriseObjValues, object userState)
    {
        if ((this.EnterpriseObjecOperationCompleted == null))
        {
            this.EnterpriseObjecOperationCompleted = new SendOrPostCallback(this.OnEnterpriseObjecOperationCompleted);
        }
        this.InvokeAsync("EnterpriseObjec", new object[] { EnterpriseObjValues}, this.EnterpriseObjecOperationCompleted, userState);
    }

    private void OnEnterpriseObjecOperationCompleted(object arg)
    {
        if ((this.EnterpriseObjecCompleted != null))
        {
            InvokeCompletedEventArgs invokeArgs = ((InvokeCompletedEventArgs)(arg));
            this.EnterpriseObjecCompleted(this, new EnterpriseObjecCompletedEventArgs(invokeArgs.Results, invokeArgs.Error, invokeArgs.Cancelled, invokeArgs.UserState));
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the URL to the WSDL.  Not sure if this is accessible outside our network.

```
http://sdrsafposent1d:8081/axis/services/grandeFacade?wsdl
```

And here is the response Fiddler captured.  My other question is with the response I see there is a Java Exception and some ugly jibberish afterwards.  Can this be causing the issue with the response not being consumed?

```
2000
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
 <soapenv:Body>
  <EnterpriseObjectsResponse xmlns="http://localhost:8180/grandeFacade/services/grandeFacade">
   <EnterpriseObjectsReturn>
    <wsResponse>
     <action>INSERT</action>
     <documentID>1000</documentID>
     <errorMsg></errorMsg>
     <objectName>enca_orden_compra</objectName>
     <stackTrace></stackTrace>
     <status>Not processed</status>
     <transactionID>1</transactionID>
    </wsResponse>
    <wsResponse>
     <action>INSERT</action>
     <documentID>1000</documentID>
     <errorMsg></errorMsg>
     <objectName>det_orden_compra</objectName>
     <stackTrace></stackTrace>
     <status>Not processed</status>
     <transactionID>1</transactionID>
    </wsResponse>
    <wsResponse>
     <action>update</action>
     <documentID>1000</documentID>
     <errorMsg></errorMsg>
     <objectName>enca_orden_compra</objectName>
     <stackTrace></stackTrace>
     <status>Not processed</status>
     <transactionID>1</transactionID>
    </wsResponse>
    <wsResponse>
     <action>update</action>
     <documentID>1000</documentID>
     <errorMsg></errorMsg>
     <objectName>enca_orden_compra</objectName>
     <stackTrace></stackTrace>
     <status>Not processed</status>
     <transactionID>1</transactionID>
    </wsResponse>
    <wsResponse>
     <action>update</action>
     <documentID>1000</documentID>
     <errorMsg></errorMsg>
     <objectName>enca_orden_compra</objectName>
     <stackTrace></stackTrace>
     <status>Not processed</status>
     <transactionID>1</transactionID>
    </wsResponse>
    <wsResponse>
     <action>Informative</action>
     <documentID>Footer</documentID>
     <errorMsg>NULL</errorMsg>
     <objectName></objectName>
     <stackTrace>none
*******************************************************************************
* Object Name: det_orden_compra
* Field Name: Unidades_ordenadas
* Field Value: 1
* Process Step: Getting primary key 
* Possible Error: Incorrect field name or value data from the key
*******************************************************************************
java.lang.NullPointerException</stackTrace>
     <status>error</status>
     <transactionID>

***********************************************************************************************
&lt;EnterpriseObjsValues&gt;
&lt;EnterpriseObjValues&gt;
   &lt;objectName&gt;enca_orden_compra&lt;/objectName&gt;
   &lt;action&gt;INSERT&lt;/action&gt;
   &lt;documentID&gt;1000&lt;/documentID&gt;
   &lt;transactionID&gt;1&lt;/transactionID&gt;
   &lt;source&gt;ORACLE&lt;/source&gt;
   &lt;whereClasue&gt;sucursal = XYZ AND orden = 34567&lt;/whereClasue&gt;
   &lt;objectDetail&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;external_id&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;345888&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;sucursal&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;XYZ&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;orden&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;34567&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;proveedor&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;45454&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;comprador&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;1001&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;tipo_distribucion&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;DD&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;order_origin&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;C&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;document_status&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;5&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;fecha_orden&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;3/13/2015 12:53:54 PM&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;fecha_entrada&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;3/20/2015 12:53:54 PM&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;fecha_cancelacion&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;3/27/2015 12:53:54 PM&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
   &lt;/objectDetail&gt;
&lt;/EnterpriseObjValues&gt;
&lt;EnterpriseObjValues&gt;
   &lt;objectName&gt;det_orden_compra&lt;/objectName&gt;
   &lt;action&gt;INSERT&lt;/action&gt;
   &lt;documentID&gt;1000&lt;/documentID&gt;
   &lt;transactionID&gt;1&lt;/transactionID&gt;
   &lt;source&gt;ORACLE&lt;/source&gt;
   &lt;whereClasue&gt;sucursal =  AND orden = 34567 AND Articulo = '1'&lt;/whereClasue&gt;
   &lt;objectDetail&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;sucursal&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;orden&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;34567&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;Articulo&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;1&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;Unidades_ordenadas&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;null&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;Costo&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;13-MAR-15&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;confirmed_quantity&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;null&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;confirmation_date&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;3/20/2015 12:53:54 PM&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;confirmation_number&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;34567&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;document_status&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;5&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;sequence&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;4567&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;requisition&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;1&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
   &lt;/objectDetail&gt;
&lt;/EnterpriseObjValues&gt;
&lt;EnterpriseObjValues&gt;
   &lt;objectName&gt;enca_orden_compra&lt;/objectName&gt;
   &lt;action&gt;update&lt;/action&gt;
   &lt;documentID&gt;1000&lt;/documentID&gt;
   &lt;transactionID&gt;1&lt;/transactionID&gt;
   &lt;source&gt;ORACLE&lt;/source&gt;
   &lt;whereClasue&gt;sucursal =  AND orden = 34567&lt;/whereClasue&gt;
   &lt;objectDetail&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;sucursal&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;orden&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;34567&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;status_proceso&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;18&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
   &lt;/objectDetail&gt;
&lt;/EnterpriseObjValues&gt;
&lt;EnterpriseObjValues&gt;
   &lt;objectName&gt;enca_orden_compra&lt;/objectName&gt;
   &lt;action&gt;update&lt;/action&gt;
   &lt;documentID&gt;1000&lt;/documentID&gt;
   &lt;transactionID&gt;1&lt;/transactionID&gt;
   &lt;source&gt;ORACLE&lt;/source&gt;
   &lt;whereClasue&gt;sucursal =  AND orden = 34567&lt;/whereClasue&gt;
   &lt;objectDetail&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;sucursal&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;orden&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;34567&lt;
554
/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;status_proceso&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;19&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
   &lt;/objectDetail&gt;
&lt;/EnterpriseObjValues&gt;
&lt;EnterpriseObjValues&gt;
   &lt;objectName&gt;enca_orden_compra&lt;/objectName&gt;
   &lt;action&gt;update&lt;/action&gt;
   &lt;documentID&gt;1000&lt;/documentID&gt;
   &lt;transactionID&gt;1&lt;/transactionID&gt;
   &lt;source&gt;ORACLE&lt;/source&gt;
   &lt;whereClasue&gt;sucursal =  AND orden = 34567&lt;/whereClasue&gt;
   &lt;objectDetail&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;sucursal&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;orden&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;34567&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
      &lt;item&gt;
         &lt;fieldName&gt;status_proceso&lt;/fieldName&gt;
         &lt;fieldValue&gt;3&lt;/fieldValue&gt;
      &lt;/item&gt;
   &lt;/objectDetail&gt;
&lt;/EnterpriseObjValues&gt;
&lt;/EnterpriseObjsValues&gt;

***********************************************************************************************

</transactionID>
    </wsResponse>
   </EnterpriseObjectsReturn>
  </EnterpriseObjectsResponse>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
0
```

Here is the block of code that  I where I am making the call and capturing the response.

```
grandeFacadeService grandeFacadeService serv = new grandeFacadeService();
WebServiceResp response = serv.EnterpriseObjects(enterpriseObjValueslist);
wsResponse[] responseArray= response.wsResponse;
```

Comment: Your WSDL link is inaccessible, but the `2000` before and the `0` after the actual soap envelope are suspect.

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be the xml itself.  If you look at the xml half way down it looks like their response was decoding the greater than and less than.